# MySQL Connection in Docker container

Tags: php, mysql, bash, docker, docker-compose

this is driving me crazy ...

I am building a simple LEMP stack with Docker on my Mac.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
        - "3333:80"
    links:
        - phpfpm
        - db
    volumes:
        - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

        - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
        - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log

phpfpm:
    build: ./phpfpm
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
        - ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html

db:
  image: mysql
  tty: true
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - /Users/mauo/local/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - "3308:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: 'docker'
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    MYSQL_USER: 'root'
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
```

Everything works fine, with exception on mysql container.

This refuses me connection.

This is the message on my php file inside code folder:

```
(HY000/2002): Connection refused in /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php on line 2
```

When I enter in mysql container with exec -it bash and I type 'mysql', the same thing, access denied for root@localhost.

From within the container, I tried to launch 'mysqld' and it tells me

```
2016-07-16T09:56:02.777893Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
    2016-07-16T09:56:02.778010Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
    2016-07-16T09:56:03.779967Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
    2016-07-16T09:56:03.780182Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

Any help would be appreciated!!!!

Thank you

M.

Comment: lets try locate the issue. Try to remove volumes from docker-compose config:
`- /Users/mauo/local/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql`